# How to convert Mono<Recipe> to Recipe without using block?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am new to webflux and I am having a tough time converting the Mono to my Recipe without using block. I tried using flatmap and subscribe, but i couldn't get it to work.

```
@Override
    public Mono<Void> deleteById(String recipeId, String idToDelete) {

        log.debug("Deleting ingredient: " + recipeId + ":" + idToDelete);

        Recipe recipe = recipeReactiveRepository.findById(recipeId).block();

        if(recipe != null){
            log.debug("found recipe");

            Optional<Ingredient> ingredientOptional = recipe
                    .getIngredients()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(ingredient -> ingredient.getId().equals(idToDelete))
                    .findFirst();

            if(ingredientOptional.isPresent()){
                log.debug("found Ingredient");
                Ingredient ingredientToDelete = ingredientOptional.get();
                recipe.getIngredients().remove(ingredientOptional.get());
                recipeReactiveRepository.save(recipe);
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("Recipe Id Not found. Id:" + recipeId);
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read up on the basics of reactive programming, just adding a `Mono.empty()` at the bottom doesnt make it reactive. Reactive means that you let the reactor establish a reactive chain of functions, so that the system, can itself switch threads when it needs to so that nothing is idleing.

You should never `block` in a reactive application. This will slow down your application and you could potentially end up with very bad performance.

So this is not allowed and should not be done.

```
Recipe recipe = recipeReactiveRepository.findById(recipeId).block();
```

So how should you do it, well you should declare a chain of functions to be performed on the returned `Producer` (Mono or Flux)

Here is one example of how it could be done.

```
return recipeReactiveRepository.findById(recipeId).flatMap(recepie -> {
    // here you will do your logic and return a Flux/Mono of something.
};
```

You are trying to write imperative code using a reactive library. For example, `null` is not allowed in `Producers` (monos and fluxes), so doing null checks is redundant is most cases.

Also reactive programming uses mostly `pure functions` so void functions or not chaining on return statements will break your code.

```
// Here you are just ignoring the return from the save, this will break the reactive chain and not be executed.
recipeReactiveRepository.save(recipe);
```

So you will always have to take care of you returns. On the other hand if you want to say ignore the return and return empty you can use the `then` operator.

So for example:

```
return recipeReactiveRepository.findById(recipeId).flatMap(recipe -> {

    // do things here then save and return

    return recipeReactiveRepository.save(updatedRecipe);

// Mono#then will make sure the return from recipeReactiveRepository#save
// is dropped, and will return a Mono#empty instead

}.then();
```

If you want to learn reactive programming i highly encourage you to read the "getting started" section in the Reactor documentation.

[Reactor Getting Started](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#getting-started)

So you understand the basic concepts, how it is written, because it is different from regular "standard" programming.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am pretty new to the reactive stuff and its a bit confusing.

Comment: The question was on-point but this answer is confusing. I have a similar use case where i want to assert the body of the mono in my test case.

Comment: If the answer is confusing then you need to read up. What the asker is asking for is impossible. A `Mono` is like a `Promise` if you call `block` the code will stop, and wait until we actually have fetched the value from the database. We dont want to do that, so instead we use things like flatMap etc, to tell the code "please code, when you receive the recepie from the data base, do this thing on the given value". If you want to test something you can block in your test case or as the documentation states use the `StepVerifier`.

Comment: the reactor documentation has an entire chapter on how to rest reactive flows. So dont blame the answer. Blame the researcher